# Mysql compare two numbers list

Tags: mysql, where-clause

How can we compare two list like this

```
A> (1,2,3,4)
B> (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

How to check if some of A list are in B list, 
I could not use IN keyword in a station like this , it will work like it was comparing strings.

Comment: Can you post pseudo-code to show your desired behaviour?

Comment: Where are these lists sourced?  a two tables (A,B)  with multiple rows or a two columns (A,B) with , separated values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can create a procedure that iterate over the first list and test it the element is in the second list.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html for more information.

Depending of the use case, you can also use a WHERE clause that check if a field is in both list.

Ex :

```
SELECT somecolumn
FROM sometable
WHERE somecolumn IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND somecolumnt IN (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```